# why Ajax Control Tool Kit is not useable

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, togglebutton

I have AjaxControlToolKit in my project's References file .
When I try to use it - 'Adding ToggleButton', the Control is not recognized as a useable control (is not found..), I am new to AjaxControlToolKit - am I missing something ? should I check something?
I am using asp.net (if it helps..)

Comment: check your web.config file check if it has the tagprefix for ajax.

Comment: If you will write it as an answer i will  mark it, thank you.

Comment: glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your web.config contains the following so that the compiler recognizes the AjaxControlToolkit controls tags when you use them:

```
<system.web>
   <pages>
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        </controls>
   </pages>
</system.web>
```

You can change "asp" to whatever you like, or you can just add this on the top of your aspx page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Hope this helps.